# AJAX request delete column base on their id.

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

Good day. I'm working on a admin page basically it is a content management system. I want to delete the data based on their id. But unfortunately i've encounter a error on the htpp request. here is the error.

```
Request URL: admin/ajax_delete
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:144.76.136.165:8181
```

VIEW FILE:

```
<a href="#" data-target="" id="delete_tpi" class="edit-content-modal1" data-id="<?php echo $ds_content->id;  ?>" value="<?php echo $ds_content->id; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>

    $("#delete_tpi").click(function() {
        alert("Are you sure you want to delete?");
        var tpi = $('.datatpi').val(); //package includes
        var did = $('#data-id').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/ajax_delete'); ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'html',
            data: {id: did, tpi: tpi},
            success:function (b){
                if (b == 'Success') {
                    $('.#data-id').val('');
                    $('.datatpi').val('');
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $('body').on('click','.edit-content-modal',function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $('#data-id').val(id);
    });
```

Controller file:

```
public function ajax_delete(){
    $did = $this->input->post('id');
    $ptpi = $this->input->post('tpi');
    $update = $this->products_model->row_delete($did,$ptpi);
    var_dump($update);
    echo ($update)?'Success':'Fail';
}
```

MODEL FILE:

```
function ajax_delete($did,$ptpi){
    $this->db->where('id',$did);
    $this->db->delete('products',$ptpi);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `<a></a>` element does not expect a `value` tag. You can get the ID of the clicked `#delete_tpi` link by using `attr()`:

```
var did = $("#delete_tpi").attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your POST request to admin/ajax_delete returns 500 Internal Server Error. This is a server-side error. If you use codeigniter, take a look at **application/logs/*.log** files that will give you detail information about the error.

I think, your problem is calling a non-existing function from model:

In your controller, you have:

```
$this->products_model->row_delete($did,$ptpi);
```

But your model, contains:

```
function ajax_delete($did,$ptpi){
    ....
}
```

Do you have row_delete() function in your model?

Once again, i suggest you to look at logs file, because many problems can result in server-side error.